# Can I specify cluster keys for Snowflake in DBT within my yaml file?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

According to current [DBT documentation for Snowflake](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/snowflake-configs#using-cluster_by), you can configure clustering in Snowflake by providing `cluster_by` into a models' `config`.

```sql
config(
    materialized='table',
    cluster_by=['col_1']
  )
```

I would rather provide these values in the model's `yml` file, like so:

```yaml
models:
  - name: my_model
  cluster_by: ['col_1']
```

***Is this possible to do?***

Comment: Check using variables in models. If a cluster variable can be defined at model level to be used in later configurations. - https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/using-variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this using a `config` resource property in the .yml file.

e.g.

```
models:
  - name: my_model
    config:
      cluster_by: ['col_1']
```

see https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/model-configs and https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/model-properties